# COMMAND: firebase apps:create android yourPackageName (android) --package-name=yourPackageName --json --project=yourPackageName

Tags: flutter, firebase

### I was connecting my app with flutter, using FirebaeCli but when i choose IOS, ANDROID, WEB it doesn't work, it shows the error below but when i choose IOS and Web as platforms it works so the solution is below

#### FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.

COMMAND: firebase apps:create android yourPackageName (android) --package-name=yourPackageName --json --project=yourPackageName ###

Answer (score 3):

## If ever you are facing this Error when using Firebase CLI

#### FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.

COMMAND: firebase apps:create android yourPackageName (android) --package-name=yourPackageName --json --project=yourPackageName ###

### This error because of the package name, you should put 2 names seperated by .